# Branch.io Deeplinking when app is not installed - avoid webpage

Tags: android, deep-linking, branch.io

I am using branch.io in my app for deeplinking and differed deep linking.

If the user does not have the app, the url registers digital fingerprint with branch server and when user installs the app, the sdk sends the collected fingerprint. the two fingerprints are matched on branch servers and data is returned to app where I can redirect user to the necessary activity.

My question: there is 2-3 second web page loading screen between link click and Google Play redirect. This is the time when branch servers are being notified of the device's fingerprint. Can I not show this webpage to user and register in some other way. I know it a very long shot but product team thinks this to be a bad user experience!

Anyone who has worked on branch please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Because you cannot access a device level ID inside the browser on Android, this makes fingerprinting a necessary trade off for designing a deferred deeplinking solution.

Branch does have a product that actually attempts to solve the problem you have, which populates the white page with a preview of in-app content. Branch takes content embedded inside the Branch link (like og_image, or og_title), and creates a template of that when a user clicks.

More information [here](https://branch.io/deepviews/).